# Handbrake --stop-at parameter not working as intended

Tags: matroska, handbrake

I run the following from command line:

```
handbrakeCLI.exe -i SourceFile.mkv -o OutputFile.mkv --stop-at 120
```

According to the [CLIGuide](http://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) you can supply the --stop-at value as seconds (which is what I want, stop encoding 120 seconds into the file).

My purpose for this is to quickly create a very high quality video clip from a full movie for testing other encoding processes.

However, when I view my output file, it is the entire movie. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I decided to solve my problem with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) as such:

```
ffmpeg -i SourceFile.mkv -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:02:30 -ac 2 -sn OutputFile.mkv
```

Explanation:

- ss : seek start, or "Begin my encoding at this point in time" (hh:mm:ss)
- t  : duration (hh:mm:ss)
- ac : audio channels, since this particular movie was having a problem disseminating the audio tracks during encoding
- sn : suppress subtitles, as ffmpeg was complaining about the subtitle track

This worked perfectly for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

The answer can be found in Handbrake's help:

```
handbrakeCLI.exe --help
```

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
--stop-at     <unit:#>  Stop encoding at a given frame, duration (in seconds),
                        or pts (on a 90kHz clock)
```

Example:

```
handbrakeCLI.exe -i SourceFile.mkv -o OutputFile.mkv --stop-at duration:120
```

This will give you the first 120 seconds of the video

Comment: Have you actually tried that? That command looks like what you want, but in my experiments it processed the ENTIRE video asset, when all I wanted was the first two minutes. Fail.

Comment: Yes I've used the command successfully. It's important to specify the duration keyword and a colon prior to the duration, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: GREAT point! Thanks for the follow up! I'm still going with FFmpeg, as I'm more comfortable with it and use it a lot.

Comment: This used to work for me, but now I was encoding a file where the `--stop-at` parameter was ignored (i.e. no matter what I set it to, `HandBrakeCLI` would always encode the entire remaining file), while the `--start-at` parameter was respected. Any clues?

Comment: Note that `--stop-at duration:120` means _encode 120 seconds_ and will _not_ stop at 120 sec into the video when combined with `--start-at` and a duration > 0. This is a little counter-intuitive and is what confused me there.

Comment: Confusing that you're supposed to put "duration" where it says "unit"! How is "duration" a unit? I wrote "s" and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2015, this is what I found, and I wonder if it would change in the future:

```
--start-at duration:120 --stop-at duration:60
```

The `start-at` duration is really "start at" some ***point***.  The `stop-at` duration is really a ***length*** (a true duration).  So the word `duration` means different things.  The line above means: start at 00:02:00, and for 60 seconds.  So a quick way to remember it is: `start-at` is at a point, and `stop-at` is for a length.